# Allow IAM user to access single s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using inline policy for grant access to s3 bucket for IAM user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1513073615000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::newput-test"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but on extended s3 browser when I use the access key id and secret access key of particular IAM user is not listing my bucket.but when I pass * in resources It works fine

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1513073615000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but the problem is its giving access to all the s3 bucket to IAM user.
but I want to give access only single bucket anybody have an idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
  {
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Its been explained here.
http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Restrict-user-access-to-Single-S3-Bucket-using-Amazon-IAM.html

Comment: Its not working giving me following error                                                               This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies.

Comment: I think this might help you.
http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Restrict-user-access-to-Single-S3-Bucket-using-Amazon-IAM.html

Comment: I have updated the answer, which might help for other who are looking for similar issue.

Comment: Ok thank you sanath, the main point is to remember here is we need to list all the bucket, this is required and we are giving permission on single bucket, listing all is required we can not achieve this without listing all.

Comment: @shubhamkatariya  that is incorrect.  You can give bucket permissions without listing permissions, and sometimes that's the right thing to do.  But some clients do not like that and respond with an error.  Most mature clients will let you use this permissions but you need to provide the bucket name directly.